# Permission denied Redshift Spring boot but works in SQL Client

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-redshift, permission-denied

I am trying to make a simple REST API to query a Redshift DB. I was granted access and can view the tables in DBeaver, but when I try to access it programmatically, I get:

```
Invalid operation: permission denied for relation "account"
```

Is this something that I am doing wrong in my code or is this a permission that I need to be granted?

For another application, we have to use AWS credentials and a AWSClientBuilder,etc. Is that the route I need to go here or can I finish my Proof of Concept with just the username and password that I use to access it on my SQL client?

Here is my code:

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:redshift://mydb.blah.region.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev?currentSchema=myschema

spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass

spring.datasource.dbcp2.validation-query=SELECT 1

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver
```

I have also tried adding `;UID=user;PWD=pass;` to the end of the datasource.url, but didn't change anything.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ContactController {
        
    private RedshiftRepo repo;
    
    @Autowired
    public ContactController(RedshiftRepo repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/get")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Contact>> getTest(){
        
        List<Contact> list = repo.findAll();        
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Contact>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/getByEmail")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Contact>> getByEmail(@RequestParam String email){
        
        List<Contact> list = repo.getContactByEmail(email);         
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Contact>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

RedshiftRepo:

```
@Repository
public interface RedshiftRepo extends JpaRepository<Contact, Integer>{
    
    @Query("select id, firstname, lastname, accountid from Contact c where c.email = ?1")
    public Contact getContactByEmail(String email);
    
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="account")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    private String id;
    
    private String firstname;
    
    private String lastname;
    
    private String accountid;

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.contactAPI</groupId>
    <artifactId>pocContactAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pocContactAPI</name>
    <description>Contact Getter</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-redshift</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.999</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
            <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42-no-awssdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.41.1065</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>redshift</id>
            <url>http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I wrote this, I was trying to put the code into a Lambda function that was on a different AWS account from the Redshift it was trying to access. The same code worked fine when I put it in the same account.

So, the problem is probably that the Lambda needed IAM/security group permissions to access the Redshift, even though I was not using the RedShiftClient.

Not sure if that is the only solution, but that is what worked for me.